# JavaEE: Pause integration test, change code, continue test

Tags: jakarta-ee, junit, jboss, integration-testing, wildfly

is there a way to pause a current integration test, change the code and redeploy it, and then resume the integration test on the paused point? My question seems to be very strange, but there have to be possibilities to change code while running the application server. Or maybe "shut down" the server (save all states), redeploying and then continue

Thanks in regards

Comment: Thing is, it is going to compile your app, and then perform the test.  You need to recompile changes, usually, and that's typically going to require you stop your test completely, since it is running the test on an already-existing jar, or set of class files

Comment: You could possibly do this by running your tests with the debugger attached and breakpoint set where you wanted and then using jrebel to make your code change. You would not be able to automate this though

Comment: Ok, thank you for your hints. If I get a good idea, I'll update this post.